# Xcode - Show message on screen (No AlertView)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, popup

I am making an thats going to show a little message on the screen. I don't want it to cancel the current touches. I don't either like to force the user to disable the view with a button as the UIAlertView does.

I have discovered a message like this in an app called "Wrapp" (with ID:458640944)

Look at the screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of a message in Wrapp]

(I don't know if it is possible to resize the image in StackOverFlow, it's to big)

Here you can see the message about the server problem for example. I want a message like this.

-Not disables the touches

-no buttons to disable

-just being there for a few seconds

Jonathan Gurebo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use one of the following libraries:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/itoast
Shows a toast-like message.

I've used this as well:

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD
comes with all sort of progress controls.

Both of them are quite easy to implement but if you have specific questions on them you can always ask.

Answer (score 2):

I achieved things you want by inheriting from [PXAlertView](https://github.com/alexanderjarvis/PXAlertView)

Answer (score 0):

The `UIAlertView` class is intended to be used as-is and **does not support subclassing**. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

So you have to customize `UIView`.

For more examples: [cocoacontrols.com-Alert View](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=alert)